# Class Variations Label Out Stock Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I need to add a css style class for only "label" products that are not in stock.

Example Original Code:

```
<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-2" title="l" for="l_2">
```

The code I want:

```
<label class="out-stock radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-2" title="l" for="l_2">
```

As you see add to the CSS code out-stock

Thanks

Edit: My product-variation.php is

```php
<?php 

/*

** Product variation hook

*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'sw_woocommerce_custom_variation', 10, 2 );

function sw_woocommerce_custom_variation( $html, $args ){

    $options   = $args['options'];

    $product   = $args['product'];

    $attribute = $args['attribute'];

    $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );

    $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );

    $class     = $args['class'];



    if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {

        $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();

        $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];

    }

    $html = '';

    if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

        $html .= '<div class="sw-custom-variation">';   

        if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {

            // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.

            $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );                                

            foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {

                $color          = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );

                $active         = ( checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) ) ? ' selected' : '';

                $attributes = ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attribute, $match ) && $color != '' ) ? 'class="variation-color" style="background: '. esc_attr( $color ) .'"' : '';



                if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) {

                    $html .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-'. esc_attr( $key .' '. $active ) .'" title="'. esc_attr( $term->slug )  .'" for="'. esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '">';

                    $html .= '<input type="radio" id="'.  esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" '. checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) .'/>';

                    $html .= '<span '. $attributes .'>'. $term->name .'</span>';

                    $html .= '</label>';

                }

            }           

        }else {

            foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {

                // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.

                $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );

                $active = ( $checked ) ? 'selected' : '';



                $html .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-'. esc_attr( $key .' '. $active ) .'"  title="'. esc_attr( $option )  .'"  for="'. esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '">';

                $html .= '<input type="radio" id="'.  esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) .'" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" '. $checked .'/>';

                $html .= '<span>'. $option .'</span>';

                $html .= '</label>';

            }

        }

        $html .= '</div>';

    }

    return $html;

}



/*

** Action hook to color

*/



$sw_attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();

if ( ! empty( $sw_attribute_taxonomies ) ) {

    foreach( $sw_attribute_taxonomies as $attr ){

        if( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attr->attribute_name, $match ) ){

            add_action( 'pa_'. $attr->attribute_name .'_add_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_fields', 200 );

            add_action( 'pa_'. $attr->attribute_name .'_edit_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields', 200 );

            add_action( 'created_term', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );

            add_action( 'edit_terms', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );



            /* Enqueue Admin js */

            add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script' ); 

        }

    }

}



/*

** Create color

*/

function sw_woocommerce_variation_fields() {

    ?>

    <div class="form-field custom-picker">

        <label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label>

        <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>

    </div>

    <?php

}



function sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields( $term ) {



    $sw_variation_color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );



    ?>

    <tr class="form-field custom-picker custom-picker-edit">

        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>

        <td>

            <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sw_variation_color ) ?>" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>

        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php

}



/** Save Custom Field Of Category Form */

function sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '', $prev_value = '' ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] ) ) {          

        $term_value = esc_attr( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] );

        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'sw_variation_color', $term_value, $prev_value );

    }

}



function sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script(){

    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' ); 

    wp_enqueue_script('category_color_picker_js', WCURL . '/js/admin/category_color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true);

}
```

As you can see on line 60 you will find the labels
Will there be any code to add a custom CSS to these labels that create the variables?

************** SOLUTION ***********

```php
<?php
    // Adiccional Class For Label Variations
    function get_variation_stock_text( $product, $name, $term_slug ){
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
            if($variation['attributes'][$name] == $term_slug ){
                $is_in_stock = $variation['is_in_stock'];
                $stock_qty   = get_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], '_stock', true);
            }
        }
        $in_stock     = ' '.__("katayainstock", "woocommerce").'';
        $out_of_stock = ' '.__("katayaoutstock", "woocommerce").'';

        return $is_in_stock == 1 ? $in_stock : $out_of_stock;
    }
        /**
         * Product variation hook
         */
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'sw_woocommerce_custom_variation', 10, 2 );
        function sw_woocommerce_custom_variation( $html, $args ) {
            $options   = $args['options'];
            $product   = $args['product'];
            $attribute = $args['attribute'];
            $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
            $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
            $class     = $args['class'];

            if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
                $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
                $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
            }

            $html = '';

            if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

                $html .= '<div class="sw-custom-variation">';

                if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {
                    // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                    $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                    foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                        $color      = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );
                        $active     = checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) ? ' selected' : '';
                        $attributes = ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attribute, $match ) && $color !== '' ) ? 'class="variation-color" style="background: ' . esc_attr( $color ) . '"' : '';

                        if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                            $stock_text = get_variation_stock_text( $product, $name, $term->slug );
                            $html .= '<label class="' . $stock_text . ' radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" for="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                            $html .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '/>';
                            $html .= '<span ' . $attributes . '>' . $term->name . '</span>';
                            $html .= '</label>';
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {
                        // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                        $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                        $active  = ( $checked ) ? 'selected' : '';
                        $html    .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '"  title="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '"  for="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                        $html    .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $checked . '/>';
                        $html    .= '<span>' . $option . '</span>';
                        $html    .= '</label>';
                    }
                }

                $html .= '</div>';
            }

            return $html;
        }

        /**
         * Action hook color
         */
        $sw_attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
        if ( ! empty( $sw_attribute_taxonomies ) ) {
            foreach ( $sw_attribute_taxonomies as $attr ) {
                if ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attr->attribute_name, $match ) ) {
                    add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_add_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_fields', 200 );
                    add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_edit_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields', 200 );
                    add_action( 'created_term', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                    add_action( 'edit_terms', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script' );
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Create color
         */
        function sw_woocommerce_variation_fields() { ?>

            <div class="form-field custom-picker">
                <label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="" size="40"
                       class="category-colorpicker"/>
            </div>

            <?php
        }

        /**
         * @param $term
         */
        function sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields( $term ) {
            $sw_variation_color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true ); ?>

            <tr class="form-field custom-picker custom-picker-edit">
                <th scope="row" valign="top"><label
                            for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td>
                    <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text"
                           value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sw_variation_color ) ?>" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
        }

        /**
         * Save custom field of category form
         *
         * @param $term_id
         * @param string $tt_id
         * @param string $taxonomy
         * @param string $prev_value
         */
        function sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '', $prev_value = '' ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] ) ) {
                $term_value = esc_attr( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] );
                update_term_meta( $term_id, 'sw_variation_color', $term_value, $prev_value );
            }
        }

        function sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'category_color_picker_js', WCURL . '/js/admin/category_color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this. And one tip, improve your code formatting because one day you need to edit this again.

```
<?php

    /**
     * Product variation hook
     */
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', 'sw_woocommerce_custom_variation', 10, 2 );
    function sw_woocommerce_custom_variation( $html, $args ) {
        $options   = $args['options'];
        $product   = $args['product'];
        $attribute = $args['attribute'];
        $name      = $args['name'] ? $args['name'] : 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $id        = $args['id'] ? $args['id'] : sanitize_title( $attribute );
        $class     = $args['class'];

        if ( empty( $options ) && ! empty( $product ) && ! empty( $attribute ) ) {
            $attributes = $product->get_variation_attributes();
            $options    = $attributes[ $attribute ];
        }

        $html = '';

        if ( ! empty( $options ) ) {

            $html .= '<div class="sw-custom-variation">';

            if ( $product && taxonomy_exists( $attribute ) ) {

                //Get product stock
                $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

                // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered. We need the names too.
                $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute, array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                foreach ( $terms as $key => $term ) {
                    $color      = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true );
                    $active     = checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) ? ' selected' : '';
                    $attributes = ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attribute, $match ) && $color !== '' ) ? 'class="variation-color" style="background: ' . esc_attr( $color ) . '"' : '';

                    if ( in_array( $term->slug, $options, true ) ) {
                        $additional_class = '';
                        if ( ! empty( $stock ) && $stock < 1 ) {
                            $additional_class = 'out-stock';
                        }

                        $html .= '<label class="' . $additional_class . ' radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" for="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                        $html .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $term->slug . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . checked( sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ), $term->slug, false ) . '/>';
                        $html .= '<span ' . $attributes . '>' . $term->name . '</span>';
                        $html .= '</label>';
                    }
                }
            } else {
                foreach ( $options as $key => $option ) {
                    // This handles < 2.4.0 bw compatibility where text attributes were not sanitized.
                    $checked = sanitize_title( $args['selected'] ) === $args['selected'] ? checked( $args['selected'], sanitize_title( $option ), false ) : checked( $args['selected'], $option, false );
                    $active  = ( $checked ) ? 'selected' : '';
                    $html    .= '<label class="radio-label sw-radio-variation sw-radio-variation-' . esc_attr( $key . ' ' . $active ) . '"  title="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '"  for="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '">';
                    $html    .= '<input type="radio" id="' . esc_attr( $option . '_' . $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $name ) . '" data-attribute_name="attribute_' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $option ) . '" ' . $checked . '/>';
                    $html    .= '<span>' . $option . '</span>';
                    $html    .= '</label>';
                }
            }

            $html .= '</div>';
        }

        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Action hook color
     */
    $sw_attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    if ( ! empty( $sw_attribute_taxonomies ) ) {
        foreach ( $sw_attribute_taxonomies as $attr ) {
            if ( preg_match( '/color|colors/', $attr->attribute_name, $match ) ) {
                add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_add_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_fields', 200 );
                add_action( 'pa_' . $attr->attribute_name . '_edit_form_fields', 'sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields', 200 );
                add_action( 'created_term', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                add_action( 'edit_terms', 'sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields', 10, 3 );
                add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script' );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create color
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_variation_fields() { ?>

        <div class="form-field custom-picker">
            <label for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text" value="" size="40"
                   class="category-colorpicker"/>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * @param $term
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_edit_variation_fields( $term ) {
        $sw_variation_color = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'sw_variation_color', true ); ?>

        <tr class="form-field custom-picker custom-picker-edit">
            <th scope="row" valign="top"><label
                        for="sw_variation_color"><?php _e( 'Color', 'sw_woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input name="sw_variation_color" id="sw_variation_color" type="text"
                       value="<?php echo esc_attr( $sw_variation_color ) ?>" size="40" class="category-colorpicker"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Save custom field of category form
     *
     * @param $term_id
     * @param string $tt_id
     * @param string $taxonomy
     * @param string $prev_value
     */
    function sw_woocommerce_save_variation_fields( $term_id, $tt_id = '', $taxonomy = '', $prev_value = '' ) {
        if ( isset( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] ) ) {
            $term_value = esc_attr( $_POST['sw_variation_color'] );
            update_term_meta( $term_id, 'sw_variation_color', $term_value, $prev_value );
        }
    }

    function sw_woocommerce_variation_color_script() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'category_color_picker_js', WCURL . '/js/admin/category_color_picker.js', array( 'wp-color-picker' ), false, true );
    }
```

Comment: Hello friend first thanks for your code.
Apparently its code works with the quantity value.

I do not use quantities only been in stock and sold out, so it does not work for me :(

I also tested their code and apparently there is an error here.

'. $ stock> = 1?' ':' out-stock '.'

Could you please verify?

Comment: I just tried and the code does not work.
This comes out.

https://i.imgur.com/WNdGas6.png

Comment: Oh common, you should see this a a developer. Just add a whitespace. I forgot it.

Comment: Not work again :( plz edit post gracias por adelantado

Comment: Yes bro
https://nikostore.net/store/E304/camisa-deluxe-blanca

Size L is sold out
A cache plugin is currently activated but to perform the tests I deactivate it.

Comment: @EduardoRafael I can't see the error on your page. Where should it be?

Comment: @EduardoRafael Check out the new code. I've also did some re-formating because  your code formatting was horrible. Please consider using an IDE with WordPress code styles option. Please try the new code and let me know if it works.

Comment: I put the code does not return any errors, but does not put the class out-stock.
It does not work. Already verify put manage stock 0 and uncheck manage stock and it still doesn't work.
It's the weirdest thing please help.
Apparently $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity(); 
It is not returning any stock value.

Comment: Currently there are 3 variations.
S, M and L


$variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
         $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
         $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

I found this code for variables will be functional?
I'm going crazy :(
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I just verified that $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
 returns no value :(

Comment: My woocommerce is Versión 3.1.2

Comment: Friend solve the return of value of get_stock_quantity () by activating the general stock manager of the entire product.

The detail is that now it returns me the same value for all the variables using its last code added.
The "L" variation is sold out and I get the same value as the others.

Comment: I was recommended to use this to get the value of sister variations
$variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

Comment: `code`//Get product stock
        $variation_ids = $product->get_children(); // Get product variation IDs

        foreach( $variation_ids as $variation_id ){
            $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
            if( $variation->get_stock_quantity() )
   $stocki = $variation->get_stock_quantity();

        }`code`